# Jupyter lab isn't starting on WSL

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

**Setups**

Running Jupyter lab installed on Windows Subsystems for Linux (WSL), which shows:

> [W 10:51:48.428 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
> [I 10:51:48.435 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/myname/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
> [I 10:51:48.435 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/myname/.local/share/jupyter/lab
> [I 10:51:48.437 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/myname
> [I 10:51:48.437 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
> [I 10:51:48.438 LabApp] http://mymachine:8910/
> [I 10:51:48.438 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

From Windows, SSH tunnel to Jupyter lab on WSL:

`ssh -N -f -L localhost:8889:localhost:8910 myname@mymachine`

**Problem**

Jupyter notebook instead of Jupyter lab was launched on Windows. That means address bar automatically jumps to `localhost:8889/tree` instead of `localhost:8889/lab`. If I force changing it to `localhost:8889/lab`, it says `404 Not found` error.

This isn't really an issue in terms of working but it just doesn't feel right. Any suggestion to fix it? Thanks!

**Update**

Couldn't fix it, so I reinstalled jupyterlab and now it worked properly.